# How can I use forall in a function definition?

Tags: idris

```
banana : Type
banana = forall x . x -> x
```

gives

```
While processing right hand side of banana. x is not accessible in this context.
```

However,

```
banana : Type
banana = {x : Type} -> x -> x

apple : forall x . x -> x
apple t = t
```

work.

How can I use universal quantification as the output of a function? If it's not possible, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forall x .` means `{0 x : _} ->` i.e. there are no `x`s at runtime. Since you use `x` in the definition, there can be no `banana`s at runtime

```
0 banana : Type
banana : forall x . x -> x
```